# T-SQL & Access :: generate LOG with not inserted values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, logging, sql-insert

I have a very old application written in `Access` that was trying to `INSERT` some data on a table on `SQL Server`.
The application was failing to insert because on that table there is a primary key.

So I solved the problem this way:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM [dbo].[Loan Type]
               WHERE [Loan Type ID] = 'HOME EQUITY')
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Loan Type] ( [Loan Type ID], [Name] )
    VALUES ('HOME EQUITY', 'Home Equity Loan')
```

And now I'm OK, all the data are inserted and those that are already there are skipped. :)

**PROBLEM**: How can I generate a log in `T-SQL` or `Access` that could tell me what data where skipped? I need something like `ON ERROR CONTINUE, LOG=<File Name> MAXERRORS=10`.

Any `T-SQL` or `Access` solution is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ON ERROR CONTINUE, LOG=<File Name> MAXERRORS=10`

SQL Server does not have functionality for your requirement. Some ETL tools, like SSIS have it though.

Therefore, you can achieve similar thing placing logic into your t-sql code:

1: `If..Else`

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM [dbo].[Loan Type]
               WHERE [Loan Type ID] = 'HOME EQUITY')
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Loan Type] ( [Loan Type ID], [Name] )
    VALUES ('HOME EQUITY', 'Home Equity Loan')
ELSE
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Log] ( [Loan Type ID], [Name], DateAdded )
    VALUES ('HOME EQUITY', 'Home Equity Loan', GETDATE())
```

2. `Try..Catch`. Something similar to:

```sql
BEGIN TRY

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Loan Type] ( [Loan Type ID], [Name] )
    VALUES ('HOME EQUITY', 'Home Equity Loan')

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Log] ( [Loan Type ID], [Name], DateAdded )
    VALUES ('HOME EQUITY', 'Home Equity Loan', GETDATE())

END CATCH
```